# Php code to write to names to a .txt file both on it's own line

Tags: php, fwrite

I am trying to get the code below to write two names (form data) on separate lines. It shows up on separate lines if I open the .txt file in Atom, but it only shows up on one line in notepad.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

  $nameOne = $_POST['nameOne'];
  $nameTwo = $_POST['nameTwo'];

  $newfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
  $txt = "$nameOne\n";
  fwrite($newfile, $txt);
  $txt = "$nameTwo\n";
  fwrite($newfile, $txt);
  fclose($newfile);
?>
```

Comment: Could be just a difference in how different editors interpret the EOL (End Of Line), have a look at the different [representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

Comment: add like this "$nameOne".PHP_EOL;

Answer (score 3):

Different operating systems use different codes. Windows is `"\r\n"`, OSX is `"\n"`
, etc. Use the `PHP_EOL` constant instead of either code for autodetection!

Go here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\r\n` instead of `\n`

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

  $nameOne = $_POST['nameOne'];
  $nameTwo = $_POST['nameTwo'];

  $newfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
  $txt = "$nameOne\r\n";
  fwrite($newfile, $txt);
  $txt = "$nameTwo\r\n";
  fwrite($newfile, $txt);
  fclose($newfile);
?>
```

OR you can use `PHP_EOL`

```
<?php
      error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

      $nameOne = $_POST['nameOne'];
      $nameTwo = $_POST['nameTwo'];

      $newfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
      $txt = "$nameOne".PHP_EOL;
      fwrite($newfile, $txt);
      $txt = "$nameTwo".PHP_EOL;
      fwrite($newfile, $txt);
      fclose($newfile);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `\n` or `\r\n` since you are using **Windows** (`\n` works well on **Unix/Linux**).